# What Happens when I change processor frequency of my android phone

Tags: overclocking, processor

I have Xolo x900 phone. I have settings to set the processor frequency.

It is defaulted to 600mhz, yet my phone has a maximum of 1.6Ghz.

Can I change to 1.6 GHz? What would be the side effects of increasing the frequency?

Will it overheat, drain my battery?

Also, would like to know what would be the advantages on increased frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting frequency to high end may cause **problems** like.

1.Heating up phone.
2.burn battery.
3.Even you may damage your phone completely.

**Over-clocking frequency will *speed up* your phone's *performance***.

Answer (score 1):

A faster clock frequency will let your phone go faster, but it comes with some costs.

The power use of the CPU is (roughly) proportional to the square of the clock frequency, so increasing from 600 MHz to 1600 MHz will use 2.5 times as much power. On top of that, that power gets turned into heat, so it'll be producing heat 2.5 times as quickly as well. Your phone will automatically slow the processor down if it gets too hot, so it may be that turning up the max clock speed actually makes the CPU slower overall - because it has to keep "throttling back" to avoid overheating.

Changing the CPU frequency doesn't make anything else faster but the CPU. That is, if you're trying to play a graphics-intensive game, it might not get faster because it's limited by the GPU speed; or if you're doing things on the web, your internet connection won't get any faster.

In this particular case, you're asking about changing the frequency within the design limits. This ought to be safe, but some mods and custom ROMs let you genuinely over-clock the processor faster than it was designed to go, or to change how and when the power management reduces the clock frequency. Using techniques like this can cause serious overheating, enough to **permanently damage** the phone's hardware. Be very cautious if you should decide to experiment.

Comment: And should you decide to test your luck, do NOT try and jump it straight up to 1.6 right off the bat, as that large of a jump is enough to potentially fry the phone.  jump it up a little at a time, let it run for a day or two, to make sure you don't have any side effects (phone rebooting, heating up too much, etc) before pushing up the speed again.